# Remove a document on a specific day - mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ttl

Basically I'm working on a project which needs to delete some document on a specific day. It is about memberships. When ones membership is expired I want that document to be deleted. But, also I want to see what documents are deleted on a later time.(Keep the object ID of that document). Following I have shown the `membership.model.js`in my code.

```
    membershipId: Number,
    startTime: Date, // Starting date and time of the membership
    endTime: Date, //Expiring date of the membership
    fees: Number,
    _active: Boolean, //membership active or not
    memberType: String
```

So basically I want to delete this documents on `endtime`. I have tried this

```
schema.index({ expire_at: endTime }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 });
```

But in a late time I can't check what documents deleted, by using the above way .It is better if I can put this `_active` variable to `false`  after the `endTime` of that document( Whithout deleting the document permanently from the DB). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

TTL is made for expiration and not archiving, it does what it says to be honest.

You can formulate a logic and use this as a solution : [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/).

Like the documentation says,

> Do not store application logic in the database. There are performance limitations to running JavaScript inside of MongoDB. Application code also is typically most effective when it shares version control with the application itself.

I would suggest that simply write a CRON job and using ***$merge*** move the content to another collection from time to time.